# why php results in HTML are undefined when using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need to get the IP of the client. I am able to get it through PHP variable
"$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']". I get this ip from server side php to html page through AJAX request but when I want to use this IP value in JavaScript it is showing that the value is undefined.
any solution?

PHP code:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<body onload='ip(); ip2();'>
<kbd id='ip' ></kbd>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function ip() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("ip").innerHTML =
        this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "ip.php");
  xhttp.send();
}

function ip2() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var ip = document.getElementById("ip").value;
    alert(ip);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Try `console.log(this.responseText)` and tell us what you see.

Comment: Does the this.responseText contain the correct IP inside the ajax callback or does that also fail?

Comment: Im getting the correct ip on the html page but when im using javascript to get this ip value it is showing undefined

Comment: heaps of sugestions on how to do it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only

Comment: well when I did what mazedlx said me to do. the ip I was getting in the html page is also now showing as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should validate that you are getting the right response from your AJAX request by check that the result is certainly written to the element with `id` attribute "ip", and than instead of using:

```
var ip = document.getElementById('ip').value;
```

You should use [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get the text content:

```
var ip = document.getElementById('ip').textContent;
```

Code example (without AJAX request):

```js
function ip() {
  document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML = '127.0.0.1';
}

function ip2() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var ip = document.getElementById('ip').textContent;
    console.log(ip);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<body onload="ip(); ip2();">
<kbd id="ip" ></kbd>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your Ip Address in java script , so have to put ip address in that tag i think.

```
<?php $ip_address =  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>

<body onload='ip(); ip2();'>
<kbd id='ip' ><?php echo $ip_address; ?></kbd>
```

Comment: well the problem is that I want the php script to be placed differently and not in the html file

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload='ip();'>
<div id='ip' ></div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function ip() {

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("ip").innerHTML =
    this.responseText;
    ip2(this.responseText);
}
};
xhttp.open("POST", "try.php");
xhttp.send();


}

function ip2(stringvalue) {
setTimeout(
       function() {
        var ip = document.getElementById("ip").value;
alert(stringvalue);
       },2000);
}
</script>
```

run this code you might found what is the problem.